# formatting gene names as text in xlsx r package

Tags: r, xlsx, r-xlsx

I am trying to format columns within an excel file in the correct manner. First of all, I am afraid that Excel pics some strange gene names as *dates* which happens often in science. So normally, when importing data into excel from a txt file, I select the gene names column and change the cell type from **general** to **text** to be on the save side.
When I now create my excel sheet using the `xlsx`, I am afraid exactly this will happen. 
At the moment I tried to reproduce this behaviour but all columns get formatted as **general** but I would love to force specific columns to text.

Is this somehow possible?

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2),
                 b=c('SEPT2', 'MARCH1'),
                 c=c('1,2', '1,4'),
                 d=c('1.2', '1.4'),
                 e=c('2-SEP', '1-MARCH'),
                 f=c('APR-1', 'DEC-1'))
wb <- xlsx::createWorkbook()
sheet1 <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, sheetName='test')
xlsx::addDataFrame(df, sheet1, 
                   col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, 'test.xlsx')
```

I would love to format column b, e and f as text.

**EDIT**

since I was asking in a comment, how I can find more formatting values for example for scientific notation, I found this [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

```
text_format = CellStyle(wb, dataFormat=DataFormat("@"))
scientific_format <- CellStyle(wb, dataFormat=DataFormat('0.00E+00'))
```

Comment: XLConnect offers more robust formatting capabilities than xlsx (while being slightly more complicated). Documentation here, see setDataFormat: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/XLConnect.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create the format specification and add it to `addDataFrame` with the `colStyle` argument.

```
wb <- xlsx::createWorkbook()
sheet1 <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, sheetName='test')

## Create the format specification
TextFormat = CellStyle(wb, dataFormat=DataFormat("@"))
FormatList = list('2'=TextFormat, '5'=TextFormat,'6' = TextFormat)

xlsx::addDataFrame(df, sheet1, col.names=TRUE, colStyle=FormatList, 
    row.names=FALSE)
xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, 'test.xlsx')
```

Note: "@" is the code for text format.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! Is there any source to look this codes up? I would love to mark some columns in scientific numbers etc... But I just can't find a good source for these codes...

Comment: Just found the scientific notation and added it to my question. I'm still interested if there is a source on how to get the format styles.